# Why can Enel be hit without Haki?

Tags: one-piece

In the Skypia Arc Enel is directly hit, although he has a Logia type Devil Fruit. Why can Enel be hit without using Haki? I know Haki was introduced a long time after the Skypia Arc. But other Logia users, like Smoker, could not get hit from Ruffy at that time.

What makes Enel different from other Logia users?

Comment: Related but not duplicate (other asker knew the answer to this question but asked if it was realistic). https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22763/is-it-logical-that-enels-power-is-ineffective-against-luffy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haki was unknown at that time so any Logia users we saw hurt were due to their specific fruit's weaknesses:

- Crocodile has the Sand Sand Fruit which is weak to moisture.  If you get sand wet it clumps and, therefore, can be hit.  Luffy takes advantage of this by getting himself wet, swallowing large amounts of water and regurgitating it, and using his own blood to wet his fists.
- Ace's fruit allows his body to be made of fire. Nevertheless, he is burned himself by the Lava Lava Fruit which is hotter.  Lava outclasses Fire.
- Enel is simpler.  Rubber is a really good insulator and is, therefore, "immune" to electricity in this story. As electricity is outclassed by the rubber, Luffy can hit him.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I thought I remembered that he had to dodge attacks from others than ruffy, too. But it's been a preety long time since I watched that arc.

Comment: @ochs.tobi he had no need to dodge most attacks (lookup enel vs kamakiri on youtube).  I do remember him dodging attacks from wiper though (seastone) but cant seem to find when that happened. Crunchyroll did just post a skypeia movie ive not watched yet.

Answer (score 6):

Haki, specifically Armament Haki, was not yet introduced as a concept yet at the time, so the only way to hurt a Logia user is to exploit their element. Luffy was already able to do this to Crocodile by dousing his body with water, forcing the sand to stick together.

Enel's body is made of lightning/electricity. He can let most normal objects pass harmlessly through his body, since most substances can conduct electricity. However, rubber is an insulator, meaning that it does NOT conduct electricity. Therefore, when Enel's electrical body comes into contact with Luffy's rubber body, he cannot conduct his body through it. So instead, his body interacts with rubber as if his body was normal flesh. This allows Luffy to inflict damage on him.

Note that rubber is not the only insulator. Glass is also an insulator, so if you were to attack Enel with a weapon made of glass, it would have the same effect. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above are straight up wrong. Logia users have to train themselves to "automaticly" become their element to ddoge attacks. Otherwhise they have to "do it" meaning that if you break theyr concentration or suprise them you can hit them.

Comment: Can you back that up with a source?